# How to randomize two times, whereas second time is disjoint with the first one

Tags: python, random

Let's say I want to randomize two times from set 1:1000. I want to sample two times 100 numbers, whereas on second time I cannot sample numbers drew in first drawing.

**My work so far**

```
import random
random.seed(42)
idx = [random.randint(0, 1000) for p in range(0, 100)]
```

And now I'm not sure how can I delete randomized indexes from numbers 0 up to 999. I tried to do:

```
without_idx = range(0, 999).remove(idx)
```

but I obtained error `AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'remove'`

Could you please give me a hand with solving this problem?

Comment: Try wrapping it in a list `without_idx = list(range(0, 999)).remove(idx)`

Comment: I tried it already, but then this error occurs: `list.remove(x): x not in list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
import random
idx = random.sample(range(1000), 200)
idx1 = idx[100:]
idx2 = idx[:100]
```

You can sample 200 numbers at once, which guarantees two sets of 100 without any conflict, then you can split that list into two

If you want the numbers to be able to be duplicated inside one set, but not between both sets you would do this:

```
import random
def avoid_conflict(excluded):
   if (value := random.randint(0, 1000)) in excluded:
      return avoid_conflict(excluded)
   return value

initial = [random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(100)]
next_set = [avoid_conflict(initial) for _ in range(100)]
```

Keep in mind, you can also use `avoid_conflict([])` if you want in the initial part if you want the code to look a little better, but it would be a tiny bit less efficient.